# H2 database - creating table form a sql file

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to create an in-memory H2 database from a SQL file as shown in the [docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).

I kept my **tables.sql** file in **src/main/resources/sql/** folder and  try to create the db as follows.

> ```
>   public static HikariConfig getHikariConfigH2(String schema, String pathToSchemaSql) {
>           HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
>
>           config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:" + schema + ";DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;"
>
>                   + "MODE=MySQL"
>
>                   + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
>                   + ";INIT=create schema if not exists " + schema + "\\;SET SCHEMA " + schema + "\\;"
>
>                   + "INIT=runscript from '" + pathToSchemaSql + "'"
>           );
>           config.setUsername("sa");
>           config.setPassword("");
>           return config;
>       }
>
>         public void testSetup() { >               HikariConfig configurationMaster = getHikariConfigH2("schema_name",
>                   "src/main/resources/sql/tables.sql");
>           DataSource master = new HikariDataSource(configurationMaster);
>        }
> ```

But it fails with following exception

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INIT[*]=runscript from 'src/main/resources/sql/tables.sql'"; expected "INSERT"; SQL statement:
INIT=runscript from 'src/main/resources/sql/tables.sql' [42001-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:991) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:951) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:764) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:50) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:63) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:267) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:252) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
```

Content of the tables.sql file is

```
CREATE TABLE item_types (
    id int NOT NULL,
    typeName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am not sure why it’s expecting an insert statement.

Could someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the unexpected second `INIT=` from the middle of SQL command in your connection URL.

```
                  + ";INIT=create schema if not exists " + schema + "\\;SET SCHEMA " + schema + "\\;"

                  + /* problem was here */ "runscript from '" + pathToSchemaSql + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks. It was clearly written in the doc http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url. Some how I overlooked. Thanks for pointing it out